# How to reverse a `recipe` from `recipes` package?

Tags: r

Suppose I am creating a recipe for my machine learning model, and I need to preprocess my outcome.

How do I reverse the preprocess my outcome or my predictors?

If I preprocess my outcome, how to reverse the output of a model to the original scale?

```r
library(recipes)

biomass <- biomass 

rec <- biomass %>% 
  recipe(carbon ~ hydrogen ) %>% 
  step_BoxCox(all_outcomes()) %>% 
  prep() 

biomass_box <- rec %>% bake(biomass)
```

In this example I have made a BoxCox Transformation on my outcome. How do I get `biomass_box$carbon` back to its original values? `recipes` may have an easy way of undoing it, but I've been unable to find it.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using `step_inverse()`?

```
library(recipes)

biomass <- biomass 

rec <- biomass %>% 
  recipe(carbon ~ hydrogen ) %>% 
  step_BoxCox(all_outcomes()) %>% 
  prep() %>%
  step_inverse(all_predictors())
```

Comment: I did, actually. This function transforms the data to a 1/x ratio

[Look at it here](https://tidymodels.github.io/recipes/reference/step_inverse.html)